# How to print tab delimited file in terminal

Tags: bash, awk, printf, line-endings

I exported excel data into a tab delimited txt file but I have hard time to print it in terminal, here is the file:

```
heading1    heading2    heading3    heading4    heading5    heading6    heading7  
col1row1    col2row1    col3row1    col4row1    col5row1    col6row1    col7row1  
col1row2    col2row2    col3row2    col4row2    col5row2    col6row2    col7row2  
col1row3    col2row3    col3row3    col4row3    col5row3    col6row3    
col1row4    col2row4    col3row4    col4row4
```

You can download the text file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3222y420e7q9rx/test_tab_delimited.txt?dl=0).

I tried with sed and awk.

update1: I  am on bsd (mac), cat file.txt prints in an ugly format that is not readable, I have a bash script that needs input tags, so I just print the tags first and choose the correct tags from the printed list

Comment: I don't understand. you can't do `cat file.txt`?

Comment: What exactly did you try and what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: What do you mean by 'print it in terminal'. Isn't cat file sufficient?

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your file:

1. It has old Mac-style line-endings.  These cause output on a Unix terminal to be overwritten in a confusing fashion
2. It lacks a final newline.

#### Using tr and echo

One way to fix this is:

```
$ tr '\r' '\n' <test_tab_delimited.txt ; echo ""
heading1        heading2        heading3        heading4        heading5        heading6        heading7
col1row1        col2row1        col3row1        col4row1        col5row1        col6row1        col7row1
col1row2        col2row2        col3row2        col4row2        col5row2        col6row2        col7row2
col1row3        col2row3        col3row3        col4row3        col5row3        col6row3
col1row4        col2row4        col3row4        col4row4
```

Here, `tr '\r' '\n'` replaces all carriage-return characters (Mac-style line-endings) with newline characters (unix-style line-endings).  The `echo ""` statement adds a final newline.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk 1 RS='\r' test_tab_delimited.txt
heading1        heading2        heading3        heading4        heading5        heading6        heading7
col1row1        col2row1        col3row1        col4row1        col5row1        col6row1        col7row1
col1row2        col2row2        col3row2        col4row2        col5row2        col6row2        col7row2
col1row3        col2row3        col3row3        col4row3        col5row3        col6row3
col1row4        col2row4        col3row4        col4row4
```

The awk program here consists of the single character `1`.  This tells awk to print each record it reads

The option setting `RS='\r'` tells awk to treat a carriage return, `\r`, as the record separator on input.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed 's/\r/\n/g; s/$/\n/' test_tab_delimited.txt
heading1        heading2        heading3        heading4        heading5        heading6        heading7
col1row1        col2row1        col3row1        col4row1        col5row1        col6row1        col7row1
col1row2        col2row2        col3row2        col4row2        col5row2        col6row2        col7row2
col1row3        col2row3        col3row3        col4row3        col5row3        col6row3
col1row4        col2row4        col3row4        col4row4
```

We use two sed commands here:

- `s/\r/\n/g` tells sed to replace carriage returns with newlines everywhere that it finds one.
- `s/$/\n/` tells sed to add a final newline at the end of each line.  This happens only once because, on input, the file has no newline characters and, consequently, sed treats the whole file as one line.

[This solution was tested on GNU (Linux) sed.  Making it run under BSD (OSX) sed may require some minor changes.]

#### Using GNU grep

```
$ grep -oP '[^\r]*(?=\r|$)' test_tab_delimited.txt 
heading1        heading2        heading3        heading4        heading5        heading6        heading7
col1row1        col2row1        col3row1        col4row1        col5row1        col6row1        col7row1
col1row2        col2row2        col3row2        col4row2        col5row2        col6row2        col7row2
col1row3        col2row3        col3row3        col4row3        col5row3        col6row3
col1row4        col2row4        col3row4        col4row4
```

This solution requires GNU `grep`.  It will not work with the default `grep` installed on a Mac.

#### Using mac2unix

Your system may also have a utility installed, probably named something like `mac2unix`, that is made to do this conversion.

Comment: How were you able to see that the Mac-style endings?

Comment: @nautical I downloaded the OP's file from the link he provided.

Comment: I see, I copy & pasted it from the website and `od -a` showed normal Unix newlines.